# rsync - exclude files in folders but include subfolders

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to setup a Perl web deployment script using rsync.

I need to exclude some files based on wildcards, but only from specific folders and not their subfolders.

If I list just the filenames to exclude then they'll be excluded from any directory, but if I include the full path (source, or destination) I can't get them to match, so they're not excluded.

The rsync commands I've tried look like this

```
rsync --recursive --force --delete --progress --exclude='$SOURCE_DIR/index.cgi' --exclude='$SOURCE_DIR/*.pm' "$SOURCE_DIR" "$DEST_DIR"
```

and

```
rsync --recursive --force --delete --progress --exclude='$DEST_DIR/index.cgi' --exclude='$DEST_DIR/*.pm' "$SOURCE_DIR" "$DEST_DIR"
```

Neither of these seems to work, and if I try this

```
rsync --recursive --force --delete --progress --exclude='index.cgi' --exclude='*.pm' "$SOURCE_DIR" "$DEST_DIR"
```

then it will exclude the files in all folders.

What do I need to do to exclude these files just from the `$DEST_DIR folder`, but not its subfolders?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with the Perl language?

Comment: `man rsync` search for `INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES`.  It covers wild-card exclusion.

Comment: If you are trying to run rsync with backticks from perl, you might be getting bitten by shell-escaping, so you may need to try escaping the `*` character.

Comment: @xxfelixxx: The issue is that something like `--exclude='$DEST_DIR/*.*'` will also exclude all subdirectories of `$DEST_DIR`, whereas the OP wants to exclude the files but include the subdirectories. I don't have a system to hand wherer I can install rsync, so I'm guessing wildly.

Comment: I think the issue might be that the OP should not use $SOURCE_DIR in the exclude pattern itself.  If that is needed, maybe try syncing from one level up.

Comment: @Borodin I've fixed the tagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$SOURCE_DIR` is used in the exclusion pattern itself.  I think rsync is only seeing the relative paths deeper than `$SOURCE_DIR`, so the exclusion is not working.

Solution is to sync from one level up.

**test_rsync.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE=testing
SRC=src
DEST=dest

rm -rf $BASE

mkdir -p $BASE/$SRC/foo/bar/baz/qux
mkdir -p $BASE/$SRC/abc/def/ghi
mkdir -p $BASE/$SRC/qwe/rty

for dir in $( find $BASE/$SRC -type d | grep "[a-z]" ); do
    touch $dir/index.cgi
    touch $dir/Foo.pm
    touch $dir/Bar.pm
done

rsync --recursive --force --delete --exclude=index.cgi --exclude=$SRC/*.pm $BASE/$SRC $BASE/$DEST

diff -r $BASE/$SRC $BASE/$DEST/$SRC | sort -r
```

**Output**

```
Only in testing/src/qwe/rty: index.cgi
Only in testing/src/qwe: index.cgi
Only in testing/src: index.cgi
Only in testing/src: Foo.pm
Only in testing/src/foo: index.cgi
Only in testing/src/foo/bar: index.cgi
Only in testing/src/foo/bar/baz/qux: index.cgi
Only in testing/src/foo/bar/baz: index.cgi
Only in testing/src: Bar.pm
Only in testing/src/abc: index.cgi
Only in testing/src/abc/def: index.cgi
Only in testing/src/abc/def/ghi: index.cgi
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work. One limitation though. I'll need to make sure that there won't ever be another 'src' (or whatever I call it) folder anywhere else in the directory tree, otherwise it may also match the exclusion rules.

Comment: Actually just figure out how to do it properly, I can do --exclude=/$SRC/*.pm This ensures that it will only ever apply at the root folder level.